# Angular Drag n Drop with line connectors

Tags: angular

hi all just want to ask if there are good open source library to achieved this kind of photo?
the idea is I want to drag and drop a logic gates example (angular framework) as it has a predefined condition and will have a connectors line which all are draggable. I am considering the angular material the drag and drop but don't know how to add some connectors with it, hope someone can point me to a good resources to start on this project. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

###### You could try [InteractJS](https://interactjs.io/).

It is a great library for making things draggable and resizable. I am positive that with some ingenuity you will be able to use it to achieve what you want.

I easily used it to add functionality to [this](http://www.laytonhedges.co.za/) interactive synthesizer, allowing me to drag buttons around and have the music change accordingly.